# static shared_ptr not keeping value across function calls

Tags: c++, exception, static, shared-ptr

I have an input.hpp (which I won't post for the sake of brevity) and an input.cpp file that looks like this (some things removed):

```
#include "details/macros.hpp"
#if defined(PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
    #include "details/win32/input.inl"
#else
    #error "No input implementation for this platform."
#endif

#define CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(type)      \
if (types[input_type_bits::type])   \
{                                   \
    auto res = poll_##type();       \
    if (res.code() != errors::ok)   \
        LOG(error) << res;          \
}                                   

namespace input
{
        void poll_input(flagset<input_type_bits> types)
        {
            CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(keyboard)
            CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(mouse)
            CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(touch)
            CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(gesture)
            CHECK_INPUT_TYPE(gamepad)
        }
}
```

And an input.inl that looks like this (also cut down for brevity):

```
#ifndef WIN32_INPUT
#define WIN32_INPUT

#include <Windows.h>

namespace input
{
        static bool g_init = false;
        static std::shared_ptr<system::surface> g_surface = nullptr;

        static error<errors> poll_gamepad()
        {
            if (!g_init)
            {
                auto ptr = create_surface();
                g_surface = std::move(ptr);
                g_init = true;
            }

            HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(g_surface->native_ptr());

            return MAKE_ERROR(errors::ok);
        }
}

#endif
```

However what is currently happening is that when I try to access `g_surface`'s method, it works for the first call (in which `g_init` was false) but in the second time the `poll_input` function is called, according to Visual Studio's debugger, `g_surface` is `empty` and accessing the method throws an exception.
What gives? `g_init` was set to true successfully across calls and yet `g_surface` wasnt? If I move `g_surface` to be a static variable inside `poll_gamepad` it does work properly but that is something I'd like to avoid. Is there something about a static `shared_ptr` that I'm missing?

Comment: Every source file that includes `input.inl` will get its own private copies of the static variables defined in that file. This is quite the opposite of the "global" concept. Surely that is not what you intended.

Comment: Suggestion: wrap  `g_surface` up in a function kind of like like a [Meyers singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301). `std::shared_ptr<system::surface> & get_surface() { static std::shared_ptr<system::surface> instance = create_surface(); return instance; }`. This eliminates the need for `g_init` and makes the initialization threadsafe. Probably eliminates the need for a `shared_ptr`, too. It's now scoped by the function and will remain alive until after `main` exits.

Comment: @paddy `input.inl` is only included in `input.cpp` throughout the entire codebase, and the other parts of the codebase only have access to `poll_gamepad` through `poll_input` which is why I don't know what is causing my issue. @user4581301 That is indeed a typo.

Comment: Recommendation: Make a [mre]. At the very least it'll reduce time wasted while we play whack-a-mole with the low-hanging fruit.

Comment: @user4581301 Unfortunately this is not a straightforward codebase to isolate. I already had to remove a lot of code just to give the examples. I will see what I can do.

Comment: If you're 100% sure about this code only belonging to a single translation unit, then the next thing to consider is whether the first call to `poll_input` might be called simultaneously from more than one thread (the init has a race condition). However, that's a pretty "out there" theory without being able to see how `create_surface` behaves in such a scenario. Another possibility is you have a memory-smashing bug somewhere (perhaps static buffer overrun), or that somewhere else in `input.cpp` can legitimately reset `g_surface`. Do a "find all" on that identifier and check all usage.

Comment: To quickly check for memory-smashing, try adding static variables both before and after the shared_ptr definition, initialized with some kind of obvious bit pattern (e.g. `static volatile uint64_t mem_before = 0xa5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5;`)

Comment: @paddy I tried the before and after variable trick but the variables seemed to be untouched. I noticed there was a problem with another static variable I had though. An std::array of std::functions which on atexit would have a memory read exception in one of the std::function's destructor. I changed it to use function pointers instead which was a bandaid fix and I never really checked what was causing it. Is there a sure way to debug static memory issues that you can recommend? If it adds something of value, the code is in a shared library and it's being called in an executable. Thanks.

Comment: Many compilers (unfortunately not as many on Windows) build in "sanitizers" to help you find hard-to-spot errors. |On GCC and clang, see if adding `-fsanitize=address,undefined` is supported by your tools. The extra checking will slow the program, but if it finds stuff, it's totally worth it . Remember to remove the option and recompile before you ship.

Comment: @user4581301 I've tried building with MSYS2's clang and aside from spewing a few exceptions from ntdll.dll which I googled and found them to be expected, nothing else showed up as being a problem. I'm completely stumped as to why I have static memory corruption as a problem in the entire codebase now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer to this problem. I mistakingly (don't code while tired people!) had a call to the Win32 API `GetKeyboardState` that was using the wrong static variable as the output buffer and caused static memory corruption.

Thank you for everyone's help and I apologize for not giving much information to deal with. That was my bad!

Anyways, I'm glad it's working properly now, case closed.